# Is video tag html5 inherit from html4 tag?

Tags: html, html5-video, html4

Can anyone pointed me to any info? I heard that video tag html5 was inherit from html4 tag. Is that true? Which tag is used for that? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you ”hear” that?...

Comment: There is no <video> tag in HTML4.

Comment: You may be confused with [embed](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_embed.htm), which does not really act the same way as `<video>`. As such, HTML5 has also included `<embed>`.

Comment: Easy on the downvotes people. It is a clear question that can be answered.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp

Comment: w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp
Is embed tag new in html5 or it's already used in html4?

Comment: The `<embed>` tag is not the same as the `<video>` tag. You should change your title and question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true. The `<video>` tag didn't exist in HTML4. At all.